# How to organize App in durandal?

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, durandal

I have created a simple durandal SPA based on tutorial from @john_papa, in this video from plural sight, he installs the nuget package but the video is already like one year old.

In that version, when the durandal package is installed it would create an App folder, and then a durandal folder with many js files there.

In the new version of durandal, there is no App folder created and instead all durandal files are created under /scripts/folder.

Based on the tutorial I created my structure like this:
http://screencast.com/t/13B4YhqExVRQ

However when I run it I got on F12 developer tools this error:
http://screencast.com/t/Sfdd0kLK

I know the path is different to the tutorial, thats why I ask how should I organize and how should I use the define method or function.

I tried

```
define(['Scripts/durandal/system', 'logger'],
```

but that didnt work

I noticed my main.js has:

```
require.config({
    paths: { "text": "durandal/amd/text" }
});

define(function (require) {
    var system = require('durandal/system');
    app = require('durandal/app');


    system.debug(true);
    app().start().then(function () {
        app.setRoot('shell');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite opinionated in that project structure can vary greatly depending on who you ask.  Given that I will give you my quick opinion -

1. Anything that you do not plan to modify should be in your scripts or vendor folder.  In the project structure you are referencing I would have my Durandal and related scripts in there.
2. Anything that you plan to modify should be separate.  If that means placing an App folder at root then do that.  I would suggest keeping it all under one directory though (such as App) so that by convention you can set up all of your routes and other application code.
3. I always use a convention of separating views and view models as Durandal 2.x suggests (root/app/views  // root/app/viewmodels) and have a well defined structure from there such as having a home directory on each side.

As far as why it isn't working currently you need to point your require.js config in main.js to the correct directory that Durandal lives in.

I would add this to your config -

require.config({

```
paths: { 
    'text': 'durandal/amd/text',
    'durandal': '../Scripts/durandal',
    'plugins': '../Scripts/durandal/plugins',
    'transitions': '../Scripts/durandal/transitions' }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This document helped me to find the problem.

http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Conversion-Guide.html